# Where is CultureInfo safed in assembly?

Tags: cultureinfo, .net-assembly

has anyone found the property or object where the Culture of the assembly is safed. 
I only found it in the **FullName** Property, already lookedd in

- Assembly Propeties
- GetCustomAttributes(true)
- GetManifestResourceInfo(resourcePaht)
- ManifestModule (satellite assembly has no ManifestModule and so no Manifest information)
- Evidence (NO)

**I´m curious who tells the assembly which culture it supports and how?**

Comment: It is set by the [assembly: AssemblyCulture] attribute in AssemblyInfo.cs.  Which should only ever have a non-empty string for satellite assemblies.

Comment: I´m talking about Properties and not about a text in a file, but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

It´s seems its really stored in the assemblyname. I create the assembly with the class **AssemblyBuilder** with the Class **AssemblyName** given to AssemblyBuilder.

**The Class AssemblyNamen contains properties for Culture, Version, Keys and so on.**

And so the AssemblyNamen contains all the important Information about the assembly.